# How to receive call programmatically without user notification in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to implement conference call. For this i tried listening phone states and as call is received from some number it makes notification to the user we want to involved in conference. Then the person receives notification make the call but i was unable to accept this call without user notification. Please suggest some method to implement this.....

Comment: I don't believe Android can natively host a conference call - IT can manage a conference call via the network operator but then it's actually the operator who is handling the conferencing aspect

Comment: This is not possible in android I believe.